# Andorid how can i add value inside of Documents array

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore

i try to add a Map item to a certain position of my Array. To do so i tried this code:

```
     String userid =FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid();
    DocumentReference washingtonRef = db.collection("Users").document(userid);

// Atomically add a new region to the "regions" array field.
    washingtonRef.update("shoppingLists[0]", FieldValue.arrayUnion("greater_virginia"));


  }
```

Here is the structure where i have to add a value:
[At this point i have to add the value](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1iZVy.png)

Answer (score 1):

You can't index into array fields like this with Firestore.  You can add or remove elements of an list type field by value using arrayUnion and arrayRemove, but you can't specify where that item is in the array.  If you need more control over the order of the elements in the array, you will have to read the document first, modify the array in memory, then update that field back into the document.